# relative pronoun after preposition

Tags: relative-pronouns

> a list of the players who have been invited.
>
> a list of who have been invited.

Can I reduce the 1st phrase like 2nd?

or should I have used 'whom' instead of 'who'?

Comment: I think you can. And I also think the 2nd phrase should be as is:  'a list of who has been invited', not 'whom has been invited'.

Comment: A list of the players invited

Comment: Yes, I think you can. It would then be a 'fused' relative construction where "who(m)" is simultaneously antecedent and relative pronoun, i.e. "the players who(m)". Since "the players" is subject of the relative clause, the pronoun should be subjective case "who".

Comment: Can you give us more context?  I'm trying to imagine a way that you could use the second phrasing, and it doesn't sound likely, but I don't want to say it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *a list of who have been invited*

Yes, it's perfectly alright to do that.

As Bill said in his comment, it becomes a 'fused' or 'free' relative clause where there is no antecedent. The interpretation of the relative clause is "the players have been invited". "Who" would be the correct pronoun because it is understood as the subject of the 'free' relative clause.

Comment: Better would be "A list of those who have been invited," as "who have been invited" should modify a noun. Otherwise "who" takes on the role of direct object, and the sentence shortens to "A list of who" with a modifying clause of "have been invited" which I don't believe conforms to standard rules.

Comment: I think this must be an open interrogative content clause and not a fused relative construction, because outside of free choice constructions (which this doesn't seem to be) and a few fossilized examples from when it was grammatical, *who* doesn't work in fused relatives, only *whoever* does.

Comment: "Send me a list of *who all* is coming to the party".  Is "who all" a variant of "whoever"?

Comment: @snailplane I came back to this question just to mention what you commented. But I am at loss distinguishing one from the other :( And if we can't prove that it's not a fused relative, we will consider this sentence to be incorrect.

Comment: @PaulM please read Snail's comment over again.

Comment: @Epicedion. "Who" is a 'fused' relative word; it contains both the antecedent and relativized element. That's what 'fused' means. So _A list of who have been invited_ would be parsed as _A list of the players who have been invited_.

Comment: @Man_From_India Thanks; actually I'm just about to reply to Snail's comment.

Comment: @PaulM Go ahead, and make clear of all the confusions :-)

Comment: @snailplane Subordinate interrogative clauses _normally_ (but certainly not always) function as complement to verbs, not nouns, for example: "I don't know _who has been invited_", where the meaning is "I don't know the answer to the question 'Who has been invited?"' When you speak of 'fossilised examples', are you thinking of an example like "Who steals my purse steals trash" from Shakespeare's Othello? I'd say that was a different use; not the same as the OP's. I do appreciate what you said about 'free choice' but I'm not sure it's relevant here.

Comment: Right, neither of those exceptions is relevant, so I think *who* would be ungrammatical if it were a fused relative.

Comment: @snailplane Interrogatives as complement of a preposition are usually introduced by an interrogative word like "whether" or "how", but there isn't one here. And I'm wondering if it does in fact qualify as a free choice construction. You may well be right, but I think I'll do a little research before conceding.

Comment: @PaulM your opinion about interrogative words that introduces interrogative clause which acts as a compliment is not fully correct. All wh-words can be used in that case. For example - "I can't help wondering what happened to my boss". Here it's very clear that *what happened to my boss* is not a fused relative construction, but an open interrogative clause. One reason being in that sentence we can't replace that *what-clause* with any equivalent NP.

Comment: @PaulM Re: fused relatives, I will take the fallback position of "It sounds really odd." In this case, at least.

Comment: @Man_From_India Ah, I actually said "... complement of a preposition..". But what I was really getting at is that the _of_- phrase is complement to the NP "a list", not to a verb, so _A list of who has been invited_ is just one big NP. I can't see how a subordinate interrogative clause can be complement to an _of_ phrase that is complement to an NP. Incidentally, the clause can be freely replaced by an NP e.g. _A list of the invited players_.

Answer (score 2):

It would most correctly be

> a list of *those who* have been invited.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Fused_relative_constructions) says that fused relative clauses should be headed by *whoever, whomever, whatever*, or *what*. The construction *"a list of who has been invited"* is a fused clause, because *who* is an object both in *of who* and the object in *whom have been invited*. So the OP's sentence is not grammatical, since it's headed by *who*.

So you could use *whoever* grammatically, as in the following example from the [M-W dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whoever):

> A prize will be given to *whoever* solves the riddle.

However, I think using two different pronouns *those who* is more idiomatic in this case. Why? Because the invitations have presumably been issued to a select group and not just anybody, and *whoever* gives the connotation that anybody is eligible.

Comment: Wiki conveniently forgets that _You can invite who you like_ is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @BillJ: That seems to be one of a few exceptions, and it may not be considered grammatical in all regions.  [See this languagelog blog post](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/myl/languagelog/archives/002690.html).

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER TO OP -**

> **1.** a list of the players who have been invited.
>
> **2.** a list of who have been invited.

OP asked whether sentence #1 can be reduced to sentence #2. I would say, it depends on context.

That *who*-clause can either be an embedded open interrogative clause or a fused relative construction. It will depend on the context. *who* can head a fused relative clause but only in very restrictive situations. On the other hand it can freely sit on the head of an open interrogative clause.

So it's very clear if the complement of **a list of** is an open interrogative clause, we can reduce sentence #1 to sentence #2. But if it's a fused relative construction sentence #2 is wrong unless it falls under "free choice construction".

---

> **3.** I don't know ***what*** she wrote. [OPEN INTERROGATIVE]
>
> **4.** I don't like ***what*** she wrote. [FUSED RELATIVE]

Consider the above two sentences. Both of them have a same *what*-clause, same structure. But they are different. In sentence #3, it's an Open interrogative clause, and in #4 it's a fused relative construction.

---

So now the question comes whether *who have been invited* in **a list of who have been invited** is a fused relative construction or an open interrogative clause. As I already mentioned, it depends on the context.

> All you have to do is to sit down and collect the responses and prepare a list of ***who*** is going to attend the wedding. [Open Interrogative Clause]

This is an **Open Interrogative Clause**, and *who* comes at its head. We don't know who is going to attend the wedding and the interrogative clause just answers - "Who is going to attend the wedding?"

> On page 40, you will find a list of ***who*** you have to write for change of address. [Open Interrogative]

This is also an **Open Interrogative Clause**. Here also the interrogative clause answers the questions - "Who you have to write for change of address?"

In OP's example sentence also it's an open interrogative - *who have been invited*.

> a list of who have been invited

Let's say there are a house full of people. Some of them were invited. We don't know who among them were invited.

> Give me a list of who have been invited.

Who have been invited? Answer to this question is listed in details in the list.

[There is no doubt but that in all these example sentences those *who*-clause after **a list of** is an open interrogative clause. But it's really hard to explain. I myself couldn't imagine any situation or sentence where a fused relative clause with *who* at its head can be placed after **a list of**]

Comment: In the interrogative reading of your example, the meaning would be "On page 40, you will find a list of the answer the question ''Who will you have to write to for change of address"'. That makes no sense at all. I don't think you've proved anything, one way or the other.

Comment: The rule *"never put who at the head of a fused relative clause"* is an ***excellent*** one to teach to ESL students. I don't think you can ever go wrong by using *those who* instead of *who* in this case, and all these complicated and rare exceptions to this rule are much too confusing, when this is a construction that native English speakers use quite rarely.

Comment: The answer is that if it can be shown to be a 'free choice' construction, then the fused reading is okay. Otherwise, it's ungrammatical. But I can't see an interrogative reading here since it can't be glossed with the usual formula "the answer to the question".

Comment: The basic distinction is between a **factive** _wh_-clause, with [presupposed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf) content -- i.e, a proposition known and accepted as true; and a _wh_-clause whose answer is unknown. The predicate decides in each case; some predicates are factive, others aren't. No matter what you call them (I follow [Ross](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CQ-DQ-New.pdf) in calling the factive ones Conjunctive  _wh_-clauses, and the unknown ones Disjunctive _wh_-clauses).

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for your valuable input. So after *a list of* the wh-clause must be a conjunctive one. Right? And that's in CGEL term a fused relative clause?

Comment: I don't know what they call it in CGEL. _List_ can refer to either one; that's just a reference to the form of the information in the clause. _The list of what they found is surprising (conjunctive)/unknown (disjunctive)_. Look to the predicate in the clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler what about *write a list of who passed the exam*?

Comment: Can you write it if you don't already know it?

Comment: @JohnLawler that's what I thought initially. If I don't know, how will the list be prepared. I am not talking about just that sentence. Talking about all the occurrence of "a list of". But then I had to change my mind. Say *write a list of who is going to attend the wedding*, here "write a list is fine", but whether Person A or Person B will join? Similarity in my last quoted example "whether to write Advocate A or Advocate B".

Comment: Another problem is that in my last two quoted example two person is involved, one speaking or giving order and the another is the listener. Now the problem is that *wh-clasue* is known to only one of them. How to judge?

Comment: You're drifting away from the core question which is: Is the OP's example a fused relative construction or a subordinate interrogative one? It all boils down to whether "who" can be used as a fused relative here. If not, one of two things is true: either it is a subordinate interrogative, or it's not. If the latter is true, it's flat ungrammatical as both a relative and an interrogative.

Comment: @PaulM actually I got a bit confused and so asked for John's help. We were discussing that same thing. But now I'm convinced and have reason to say firmly that OP's examples are correct and this is an example of open interrogative clause.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I've heard any 'new' and convincing evidence, to be honest. I'm taking advice and will get back to you asap.

Comment: @PaulM sure. Actually I don't know how to explain it here. Let's see if I can find out. You can also give your valuable inputs.

Comment: At last I have an answer to this conundrum! It is an interrogative. “Who” – unlike "what” or “whoever” – cannot normally occur in the fused relative construction. So you can’t say, for example, *_Who has/have been invited hasn’t/haven’t replied yet_. My original analysis was wrong; sorry about that.

Comment: @PaulM that's completely okay, and I myself could not give you enough reason to change your mind :-) it was nice talking to you.

Comment: Please see the language blog post provided by @Peter Shor.